# UIWebView to WKWebView on youtube-ios-player-helper-swift

Tags: swift, ytplayerview

My app uses the framework youtube-is-player-helper-swift, found here: https://github.com/malkouz/youtube-ios-player-helper-swift
It is an implementation of the original youtube-ios-player-helper, for Swift.
It is working fine, but it is based on UIWebView, deprecated in iOS 12.
I'm looking for a version of this framework using WKWebView or some help to change this one. 
Anyone can point me to a possible solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [youtube helper](https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView)

from hmhv. Which uses WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

Comment: thank you for your answer...I'm familiar with youtube helper. But I was looking for something in Swift instead of ObjectiveC...mostly because I'm new in XCode and not even sure how to use an ObjectiveC framework

Comment: Just add it to the project and use it like any other Swift framework. No need to write any objective c code.